# Unmarshal sets inner object value as json string

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-firestore, unmarshalling

I'm reading data from firebase, and the response is as "map[string]interface{}", for example:

```
Response: {
 Id: 1,
 Name: "Marwan",
 Career: {
  employeer: "mycompany",
  salary: "100",
 }
}
```

I have a struct as:

```
type Employee struct {
 Id int
 Name string
 Career CareerType
}

type CareerType struct {
 Employeer string
 Salary string
}
```

when I do the following:

```
marshal, _ := json.Marshal(data)
json.Unmarshal(marshal, Emplyee{})
```

The result will be as:

```
Reposnse: {
 Id: 1,
 Name: "Marwan",
 Career: "{\"employeer\":\"mycompany\", \"salary\":\"100\"}"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the inner object (Career in this case) is not being unmarshalled to an object? shouldn't unmarshal operation do this implicitly?

Comment: I don’t see how a struct type (the word `struct` is missing, btw) can have a string value. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: your code examples has many syntax errors. `CareerType` missing `struct` and every struct field has commas, they don't need in Go. And what is your `data`? If you have `json string` mention it in the problem, and what you need to marshal or unmarshal?

Comment: @nipuna you are right, I fixed the things you mentioned. The struct doesn't has json string values, I need to unmarshal the response from firestore to a struct object,

Comment: Use ```type CareerType struct {
 Employer string `json:"employer"`
 Salary    string `json:"salary"`
}` ``` as your `CareerType`.

Comment: You are also calling `json.Unmarshal` on a non-pointer value, which should panic on running. Also, what exactly is the "result"? How do you get the "result"?

Comment: (adding the the "please show a minimal reproducible example" list of comments) : when you say "The result will be as: ...", you don't show the code or the action that produces this output. Please explain what element of your project (go code printing on stdout ? a tool connected some api ? ... ) ends up printing this output. Also : fix the typos (`Reposnse`, `employeer` or `Employeer`, etc ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you marshal the data, you would need to only pass in the element that corresponds to your struct. For example:

```
bytes, _ := json.Marshal(data["Response"])
```

Afterwards unmarshalling should work as expected:

```
var employee Employee
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &employee)
```

`employee` should now look as follows:

```
{Id:1 Name:Marwan Career:{Employer:mycompany Salary:100}}
```